Getting errors while opening workflow as designer in azure logic apps standard on vs code

When I'm opening logic app workflow as designer, I'm getting the below errors.
Error in determining project root. Please confirm project structure is correct.
EnvironmentCredential is unavailable. No underlying credential could be used. To troubleshoot, visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/js/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot.

How to solve this issue

Have you tried signing in using different ways and opening the logic app with its root path?


Error in determining project root. Please confirm project structure is correct.

This error stating that you have not opened the root folder of the Logic App so that the designer is unable to open.
To open your .json file (workflow) as designer, open the root folder as you can see the below screenshot that I have created the logic app same like you and opened the root folder which is the logic app workspace here:

From your screenshot, azlogicapps is the folder and vacstdlogicapp is the logic app’s workspace which is the root folder for opening the workflows in designer format.
EnvironmentCredential is unavailable. No underlying credential could be used. To troubleshoot, visit https://aka.ms/azsdk/js/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot.

From my experience, this is caused due to several reasons such as:

Multiple sign-in accounts in VS code or
Authentication and authorization not happened correctly in the VS Code by your Azure Accounts (or)
Unable to determine the Tenant of your Azure account by VS Code.

Though you have logged in already to VS code, you have to do small things like:
4. Open Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P - Windows Shortcut) in your VS Code, then sign in to tenant directly as I shown below:

